# How to Disable SSL on asp.net MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So i was trying something and enabled SSL on my mvc5 project. Now i want to disable it, but whenever i run my project, the web site cannot be found (the url is different from the ssl one ofc). Any idea how to turn ssl back off ?

Comment: does the answer here help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338368/unable-to-disable-ssl-for-website

Comment: no :S because i only have the    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); attribute on that method :S

Comment: create a filter attribute and do the opposite of this http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/requiring-ssl-for-asp-net-mvc-controllers

Answer (score 14):

All of the above sound plausible, and none of them works for me!  I have no strange filters, no RequireHttps decorations and no https ports.  So my current only fix is to change the project property:

[image]

I can then happily debug and browse my test website.  But if I exit Visual Studio and go back in, I have to reset the SSL enabled property again!

So this is only half an answer, but thought it might help someone ...

Comment: I also had to use Google chrome instead of Firefox ...

Answer (score 13):

For me the solution was to remove

```
    [RequireHttps]
```

from the index method inside the home controller

Comment: Thanks, this answer led me to do a string search, which ultimately made me find this code that was actually causing my issue: `filters.Add(new RequireHttpsUnlessLocalAttribute());` thanks for your answer!

Comment: Saved my time, thanks, I forgot to remove [RequireHttps] after disabling SSL

Comment: I had enabled SSL on my web project in VS 2017.  Then changed the property back to false.  It added the RequireHttps attribute to the home controller but did not remove it.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem.

**Project >  Properties... > Web > Servers (IIS Express) > Project Url**

Change:

`https://localhost:20555`

to
`http://localhost:20555`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in .NET 5 application. Go to Project Properties-> Debug-> Disable "Enable SSL"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to disabling "RequireHttps", you should also remove [RequireHttps] from your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Re-create the project without SSL required will be fastest in Visual Studio environment.