# Removing SSL From an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I remove SSL from my asp.net mvc site in Visual Studio?

When I change SSL from `True` to `False` it shows this error:

[image: SSL removal error]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338368/unable-to-disable-ssl-for-website

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy the URL.
2. In Solution Explorer, right click the project name and select Properties.
3. Select the Web tab, and then paste the URL into the Project Url box. Save the file (Ctl+S).
4. now change SSL from True to False.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Have a look in your FilterConfig.cs file and remove the line that says. filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); Line.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
    filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); 
}
```